# Is vb.net slow?

Tags: c#, vb.net, algorithm

I have the same project written with Vb.net and C # prepared with Visual Studio 2015 below. 
Visual Basic project:

```vb
Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    Dim j As Int32 = 0
    '
    Dim Offset As Double = 0D   ' Offset
    Dim Gain As Double = 1D     ' Gain
    Dim Freq As Double = 1D     ' Frequency
    Dim M As Int32 = 3000    ' Number of Block
    Dim N As Int32 = 30000    ' Number of data each block
    Dim delta As Double = 0     ' Sample rate
    Dim DataCount As Int32 = N * M  ' Total data count   
    '
    Dim X As Double
    Dim Y As Double
    '
    delta = N / DataCount
    '
    ' Fonksiyon
    '
    Dim Time As Stopwatch
    Time = New Stopwatch
    Time.Start()
    '
    For b As Int32 = 0 To M - 1
        For i As Int32 = 0 To N - 1
            X = j * delta
            Y = Offset + Gain * Math.Cos(X * Freq * Math.PI / 180.0)
            j = j + 1
        Next
    Next b
    '
    Time.Stop()
    Console.WriteLine("Elapsed time :{0}", Time.Elapsed)
End Sub
```

and C# project:

```c#
 private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        Int32 j = 0;

        Double Offset = 0D;  // Offset
        Double Gain = 1D;     // Gain
        Double Freq = 1D;     // Frequency
        Int32 M = 3000;    // Number of Block
        Int32 N = 30000;    // Number of data each block
        Double delta = 0;     // Sample rate
        Int32 DataCount = N * M;  // Total data count   
        //
        Double X;
        Double Y;
        //
        delta = N / DataCount;
        //
        // Fonksiyon
        //
        Stopwatch Time;
        Time = new Stopwatch();
        Time.Start();
        //
        for (Int32 b=0; b< M; b++) {

            for (Int32 i= 0; i < N; i++) {
            X = j * delta;
            Y = Offset + Gain * Math.Cos(X * Freq * Math.PI / 180.0);
            j = j + 1;
            }
        }
        //
        Time.Stop();
        Console.WriteLine("Elapsed time :{0}", Time.Elapsed);
    }
```

The projects were run three times and delay times were obtained.

Results obtained when the Visual Basic project is run;

```
Elapsed time :00:00:03.9066617
Elapsed time :00:00:03.9165436
Elapsed time :00:00:03.9031542
```

And the results obtained when the C # project is run;

```
Elapsed time :00:00:02.4870551
Elapsed time :00:00:02.4931171
Elapsed time :00:00:02.5005793
```

Different result in the same framework. There is more than a second difference between vb.net and C#.

Why is vb.net so slow?

Comment: Did you test this in release, did you use a respectable bench-marking tool

Comment: Did you try to reset your pc and run these programs in inverse order. I mean first the C# one then the VB.NET one. Measuring performance is not as simple as starting two Stopwatch around a loop. By the way did you set the two codes in release mode?

Comment: If you want to know if there's a difference, check the generated IL for the two code snippets.  By the way, you only need one line to create and start a `Stopwatch`, i.e. `Dim time = Stopwatch.StartNew()`.

Comment: Try enabling unchecked arithmetic in the advanced compile options of the vb project. The generated IL is using the `.ovf` opcodes which are performing overflow checks. Also either switch the division in vb from `/` to `\ ` the latter of which performs integer division, modify the c# so it's *not* integer division (cast one side to a double) OR use values that will at least behave the same for integer/float division. Compile in release mode, run *outside* of visual studio, perform more than three tests (warmup the jit and drop a bunch) and use a proper benchmark framework

Comment: Thanks for your comments. As Pinkfloydx33 mentioned, there was a problem with the splitting process.

Answer (score 3):

The two codes have an important difference in this line:

```
delta = N / DataCount
```

In VB, this is arithmetical division. In C#, it is integer division.
In VB it returns `0.00033333...`, in C# it returns 0.

If you fix the VB code to also use integer division:

```
delta = N \ DataCount
```

the two codes begin to show exactly the same time.

Comment: I will also check the IL code as well. That is interesting to know, never used VB.net before.

Comment: The vb is also generating overflow opcodes (`.ovf`). Enabling unchecked arithmetic in the advanced compile options of the VB project should fix that and make them even closer

Comment: Thanks Gserg. You have found an important error that has been missed. pinkfloydx33 also mentioned. In both projects, when delta = 0.000333 is received, very close time is obtained.

Answer (score 0):

Please check the generated IL code for `C#` and `VB.Net`. In my local machine, I observed that they are roughly equivalent but not the same. For example, In the case of VB.Net, it has extra checks for arithmetic addition, subtraction etc. `VB.NET` uses opcodes such as `sub.ovf`, `mul.ovf` where as C# does not. I am providing the IL output for both cases. They are compile using release mode. You can see that they start to differ even from the number of local variables. VB has 13 locals where as C# 11 locals.

C#

```
 .method /*06000002*/ private hidebysig instance void 
    button1_Click(
      /*08000001*/ object sender, 
      /*08000002*/ class [mscorlib/*23000001*/]System.EventArgs/*01000014*/ e
    ) cil managed 
  {
    .maxstack 2
    .locals /*11000002*/ init (
      [0] int32 j,
      [1] float64 Offset,
      [2] float64 Gain,
      [3] float64 Freq,
      [4] int32 M,
      [5] int32 N,
      [6] float64 delta,
      [7] int32 DataCount,
      [8] float64 X,
      [9] class [System/*23000003*/]System.Diagnostics.Stopwatch/*01000015*/ Time,
      [10] int32 b,
      [11] int32 i
    )

    // [38 13 - 38 25]
    IL_0000: ldc.i4.0     
    IL_0001: stloc.0      // j

    // [40 13 - 40 32]
    IL_0002: ldc.r8       0.0
    IL_000b: stloc.1      // Offset

    // [41 13 - 41 30]
    IL_000c: ldc.r8       1
    IL_0015: stloc.2      // Gain

    // [42 13 - 42 30]
    IL_0016: ldc.r8       1
    IL_001f: stloc.3      // Freq

    // [43 13 - 43 28]
    IL_0020: ldc.i4       3000 // 0x00000bb8
    IL_0025: stloc.s      M

    // [44 13 - 44 29]
    IL_0027: ldc.i4       30000 // 0x00007530
    IL_002c: stloc.s      N

    // [45 13 - 45 30]
    IL_002e: ldc.r8       0.0
    IL_0037: stloc.s      delta

    // [46 13 - 46 37]
    IL_0039: ldloc.s      N
    IL_003b: ldloc.s      M
    IL_003d: mul          
    IL_003e: stloc.s      DataCount

    // [51 13 - 51 35]
    IL_0040: ldloc.s      N
    IL_0042: ldloc.s      DataCount
    IL_0044: div          
    IL_0045: conv.r8      
    IL_0046: stloc.s      delta

    // [56 13 - 56 36]
    IL_0048: newobj       instance void [System/*23000003*/]System.Diagnostics.Stopwatch/*01000015*/::.ctor()/*0A00001D*/
    IL_004d: stloc.s      Time

    // [57 13 - 57 26]
    IL_004f: ldloc.s      Time
    IL_0051: callvirt     instance void [System/*23000003*/]System.Diagnostics.Stopwatch/*01000015*/::Start()/*0A00001E*/

    // [59 18 - 59 29]
    IL_0056: ldc.i4.0     
    IL_0057: stloc.s      b

    IL_0059: br.s         IL_009b
    // start of loop, entry point: IL_009b

      // [62 22 - 62 33]
      IL_005b: ldc.i4.0     
      IL_005c: stloc.s      i

      IL_005e: br.s         IL_008f
      // start of loop, entry point: IL_008f

        // [64 21 - 64 35]
        IL_0060: ldloc.0      // j
        IL_0061: conv.r8      
        IL_0062: ldloc.s      delta
        IL_0064: mul          
        IL_0065: stloc.s      X

        // [65 21 - 65 78]
        IL_0067: ldloc.s      X
        IL_0069: ldloc.3      // Freq
        IL_006a: mul          
        IL_006b: ldc.r8       3.14159265358979
        IL_0074: mul          
        IL_0075: ldc.r8       180
        IL_007e: div          
        IL_007f: call         float64 [mscorlib/*23000001*/]System.Math/*01000024*/::Cos(float64)/*0A00001F*/
        IL_0084: pop          

        // [66 21 - 66 31]
        IL_0085: ldloc.0      // j
        IL_0086: ldc.i4.1     
        IL_0087: add          
        IL_0088: stloc.0      // j

        // [62 42 - 62 45]
        IL_0089: ldloc.s      i
        IL_008b: ldc.i4.1     
        IL_008c: add          
        IL_008d: stloc.s      i

        // [62 35 - 62 40]
        IL_008f: ldloc.s      i
        IL_0091: ldloc.s      N
        IL_0093: blt.s        IL_0060
      // end of loop

      // [59 38 - 59 41]
      IL_0095: ldloc.s      b
      IL_0097: ldc.i4.1     
      IL_0098: add          
      IL_0099: stloc.s      b

      // [59 31 - 59 36]
      IL_009b: ldloc.s      b
      IL_009d: ldloc.s      M
      IL_009f: blt.s        IL_005b
    // end of loop

    // [70 13 - 70 25]
    IL_00a1: ldloc.s      Time
    IL_00a3: callvirt     instance void [System/*23000003*/]System.Diagnostics.Stopwatch/*01000015*/::Stop()/*0A000020*/

    // [71 13 - 71 66]
    IL_00a8: ldstr        "Elapsed time :{0}"
    IL_00ad: ldloc.s      Time
    IL_00af: callvirt     instance valuetype [mscorlib/*23000001*/]System.TimeSpan/*01000025*/ [System/*23000003*/]System.Diagnostics.Stopwatch/*01000015*/::get_Elapsed()/*0A000021*/
    IL_00b4: box          [mscorlib/*23000001*/]System.TimeSpan/*01000025*/
    IL_00b9: call         void [mscorlib/*23000001*/]System.Console/*01000026*/::WriteLine(string, object)/*0A000022*/

    // [72 9 - 72 10]
    IL_00be: ret          

  } // end of method Form1::button1_Click
```

VB.NET

```
    .method /*06000014*/ private instance void 
        Button1_Click(
          /*08000005*/ object sender, 
          /*08000006*/ class [mscorlib/*23000001*/]System.EventArgs/*01000027*/ e
        ) cil managed 
      {
        .maxstack 2
        .locals /*11000002*/ init (
          [0] int32 j,
          [1] float64 Offset,
          [2] float64 Gain,
          [3] float64 Freq,
          [4] int32 M,
          [5] int32 N,
          [6] float64 delta,
          [7] int32 DataCount,
          [8] float64 X,
          [9] class [System/*23000002*/]System.Diagnostics.Stopwatch/*0100002C*/ Time,
          [10] int32 V_10,
          [11] int32 b,
          [12] int32 V_12,
          [13] int32 i
        )

        // [3 13 - 3 27]
        IL_0000: ldc.i4.0     
        IL_0001: stloc.0      // j

        // [5 13 - 5 34]
        IL_0002: ldc.r8       0.0
        IL_000b: stloc.1      // Offset

        // [6 13 - 6 32]
        IL_000c: ldc.r8       1
        IL_0015: stloc.2      // Gain

        // [7 13 - 7 32]
        IL_0016: ldc.r8       1
        IL_001f: stloc.3      // Freq

        // [8 13 - 8 30]
        IL_0020: ldc.i4       3000 // 0x00000bb8
        IL_0025: stloc.s      M

        // [9 13 - 9 31]
        IL_0027: ldc.i4       30000 // 0x00007530
        IL_002c: stloc.s      N

        // [10 13 - 10 32]
        IL_002e: ldc.r8       0.0
        IL_0037: stloc.s      delta

        // [11 13 - 11 39]
        IL_0039: ldloc.s      N
        IL_003b: ldloc.s      M
        IL_003d: mul.ovf      
        IL_003e: stloc.s      DataCount

        // [17 9 - 17 30]
        IL_0040: ldloc.s      N
        IL_0042: conv.r8      
        IL_0043: ldloc.s      DataCount
        IL_0045: conv.r8      
        IL_0046: div          
        IL_0047: stloc.s      delta

        // [22 9 - 22 29]
        IL_0049: newobj       instance void [System/*23000002*/]System.Diagnostics.Stopwatch/*0100002C*/::.ctor()/*0A000040*/
        IL_004e: stloc.s      Time

        // [23 9 - 23 21]
        IL_0050: ldloc.s      Time
        IL_0052: callvirt     instance void [System/*23000002*/]System.Diagnostics.Stopwatch/*0100002C*/::Start()/*0A000041*/

        // [25 9 - 25 36]
        IL_0057: ldloc.s      M
        IL_0059: ldc.i4.1     
        IL_005a: sub.ovf      
        IL_005b: stloc.s      V_10
        IL_005d: ldc.i4.0     
        IL_005e: stloc.s      b

        IL_0060: br.s         IL_00a8
        // start of loop, entry point: IL_00a8

          // [26 13 - 26 40]
          IL_0062: ldloc.s      N
          IL_0064: ldc.i4.1     
          IL_0065: sub.ovf      
          IL_0066: stloc.s      V_12
          IL_0068: ldc.i4.0     
          IL_0069: stloc.s      i

          IL_006b: br.s         IL_009c
          // start of loop, entry point: IL_009c

            // [27 17 - 27 30]
            IL_006d: ldloc.0      // j
            IL_006e: conv.r8      
            IL_006f: ldloc.s      delta
            IL_0071: mul          
            IL_0072: stloc.s      X

            // [28 17 - 28 73]
            IL_0074: ldloc.s      X
            IL_0076: ldloc.3      // Freq
            IL_0077: mul          
            IL_0078: ldc.r8       3.14159265358979
            IL_0081: mul          
            IL_0082: ldc.r8       180
            IL_008b: div          
            IL_008c: call         float64 [mscorlib/*23000001*/]System.Math/*01000038*/::Cos(float64)/*0A000042*/
            IL_0091: pop          

            // [29 17 - 29 26]
            IL_0092: ldloc.0      // j
            IL_0093: ldc.i4.1     
            IL_0094: add.ovf      
            IL_0095: stloc.0      // j

            // [30 13 - 30 17]
            IL_0096: ldloc.s      i
            IL_0098: ldc.i4.1     
            IL_0099: add.ovf      
            IL_009a: stloc.s      i

            IL_009c: ldloc.s      i
            IL_009e: ldloc.s      V_12
            IL_00a0: ble.s        IL_006d
          // end of loop

          // [31 9 - 31 15]
          IL_00a2: ldloc.s      b
          IL_00a4: ldc.i4.1     
          IL_00a5: add.ovf      
          IL_00a6: stloc.s      b

          IL_00a8: ldloc.s      b
          IL_00aa: ldloc.s      V_10
          IL_00ac: ble.s        IL_0062
        // end of loop

        // [33 9 - 33 20]
        IL_00ae: ldloc.s      Time
        IL_00b0: callvirt     instance void [System/*23000002*/]System.Diagnostics.Stopwatch/*0100002C*/::Stop()/*0A000043*/

        // [34 9 - 34 61]
        IL_00b5: ldstr        "Elapsed time :{0}"
        IL_00ba: ldloc.s      Time
        IL_00bc: callvirt     instance valuetype [mscorlib/*23000001*/]System.TimeSpan/*01000039*/ [System/*23000002*/]System.Diagnostics.Stopwatch/*0100002C*/::get_Elapsed()/*0A000044*/
        IL_00c1: box          [mscorlib/*23000001*/]System.TimeSpan/*01000039*/
        IL_00c6: call         void [mscorlib/*23000001*/]System.Console/*0100003A*/::WriteLine(string, object)/*0A000045*/

        // [35 5 - 35 12]
        IL_00cb: ret          

      } // end of method Form1::Button1_Click
```

Comment: FYI, your locals counts are *off by one* (s/b 14 and 12) but I doubt the count matters much, the two extras are being used as temporaries...though it does highlight that the two are different

Comment: @pinkfloydx33, yeah that is what I wrote in my answer locals are different

Comment: I meant, you didn't count right. You have an "off by one" error (0 based indexes)

Comment: @pinkfloydx33, oh yeah you are right!! Side effects of trying to answer after abusy day at work. I will fix them